# JPA 2.1 Entity Listener doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

*If you set minus, provide feedback. Let critic be constructive, please.*

I have three projects with following structure:

core (simple JAR, some base entities)

- package1.BaseEntity (@MappedSuperclass and @EntityListeners(BaseEntityListener.class)
- package1.BaseEntityListener

web (Spring Boot App (entities, JPA repositories, MVC, etc)

- package2.AuditEntityListener
- src/main/resources/audit-listeners.xml
- src/main/resources/persistence.xml

users (Spring Boot App (additional entities and JPA Repositories for users))

I specified AuditEntityListener in audit-listeners.xml file and include them into mapping-file tag in persistence.xml. But all entity listeners don't work. It also doesn't work there is not BaseEntityListener. I tried to use Spring's AuditingEntityListener with the same result. I'm using JPA 2.1, Spring Boot 1.4.0, Hibernate 5.0.9-Final, Java 1.8, maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of projects structure. Making each persistence units have own listeners solved problem.